# Personalización de gráficas chartjs

Tags: jquery, chart.js

Desde hace unos días estoy trabajando con este plugin de jQuery para generar mis gráficas.

Puesto que la documentación está completamente en inglés me cuesta un poco identificar cada elemento que se menciona y sus posibles configuración para la personalización visual del mismo. Por eso acudo aquí para resolver algunas dudas.

Al utilizar la gráfica `polarArea` me encuentro con este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me ha llamado la atención el hecho de que en mi caso aparece en el lateral izquierdo una línea con números que no quiero que aparezca, ilustro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otra parte también me gustaría poder poner estos elementos en el lado derecho en modo de lista por ejemplo `<ul>`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

codigo:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("reporte_tecnicos").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
 labels: ["tec1", "tec2", "tec3",],
 datasets: [{
  label: '',
  backgroundColor: [
   "rgba(0, 150, 254, 0.5)",
   "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
   "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)",
   "rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.5)",
   "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
   "rgba(100, 254, 0.5)",
   "rgba(25, 100, 200, 0.5)",
   "rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.5)",
   "rgba(80, 20, 0, 0.5)",
   "rgba(255, 50, 254, 0.5)"
  ],
  data: [3, 2, 3,],
 }]
},
options: {
 scales: {
  yAxes: [{
   ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true
   }
  }]
 }
}
});
// REPORTE DE P
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="tecnician">
 <center><h3>Estadísticas de técnicos</h3></center>
 <div class="well" id="reporte_tecnicos_div">
  <canvas id="reporte_tecnicos" style="max-width: 50%; margin: 1px auto; float;none;"></canvas>
 </div>
</section>
```

documentación:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Comment: Pavio, que tal si pones algo de código para así no trabajar desde 0.

Comment: Pavio, crees que puedas poner los data, directamente sin agregar el PHP, porque no se puede ejecutar. Agrega los data sin el Array ya interpretado.

Comment: Ya está, disculpa se me había psado.

Comment: Agrega la libreria al Snippet,  le falta la librería Chart. Please

Comment: No la encuentro, yo descargué el plugin direcamente... no estoy seguro de que tenga la libreria para ponerla "online"...

Comment: @PavloB. en tu código dice: `type: 'bar'`, pero las imágenes corresponden a `type: 'polarArea'`. también, si es posible "y ayudaría mucho" si creas un ejemplo en jsfiddle "entiendo lo que dijiste en tu comentario", pero [he encontrado un ejemplo en jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksr9ucvb/1/) que venía en otra [pregunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237181/chart-js-polar-area-chart-is-not-scale-right#comment62110495_37261446) el cuale stoy tratando de modificar.

Comment: Lo del `type: 'bar' ` es porque lo copié tal cual de mi código y lo dejé en bar hasta que sea capaz de tenerlo como quiero con el polar area. El ejemplo que pusiste del jsfiddle me sirve igual, es solamente el poder configurar lo que menciono en la pregunta. Gracuas

Comment: @PavloB. para quitar los números al lado izquierdo de tu gráfica, quita el objeto `options`.

Comment: Si quito options entonces no puedo editar las opciones, y la configuración de beginAtZero no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estabas buscando algo así?

[image: Chart]

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("reporte_tecnicos").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'polarArea',
data: {
    labels: ["tec1", "tec2", "tec3", ],
    datasets: [{
        label: '',
        backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(0, 150, 254, 0.5)",
            "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
            "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)",
            "rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.5)",
            "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
            "rgba(100, 254, 0.5)",
            "rgba(25, 100, 200, 0.5)",
            "rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.5)",
            "rgba(80, 20, 0, 0.5)",
            "rgba(255, 50, 254, 0.5)"
        ],
        data: [3, 2, 3, ],
    }]
},
options: {
    legend: {
        position: 'right'
    },
    scale: {
        display: false
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<section id="tecnician">
<center><h3>Estadísticas de técnicos</h3></center>
<div class="well" id="reporte_tecnicos_div">
 <canvas id="reporte_tecnicos" style="max-width: 50%; margin: 1px auto; float;none;"></canvas>
</div>
</section>
```

Básicamente cambié la posición de la leyenda hacia la derecha utilizando `legend: { position: 'right'}` y ocultando las líneas de las escalas con `scale: { display: false }`.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el ejemplo basado en tu información, espero te sirva, saludos.

```js
var data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [
            3, 2, 3
        ],
        backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(0, 150, 254, 0.5)",
   "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
   "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)",
   "rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.5)",
   "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
   "rgba(100, 254, 0.5)",
   "rgba(25, 100, 200, 0.5)",
   "rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.5)",
   "rgba(80, 20, 0, 0.5)",
   "rgba(255, 50, 254, 0.5)"
        ],
        label: '' 
    }],
    labels: [
        "tec1", "tec2", "tec3"
    ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("reporte_tecnicos").getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, {
    data: data,
    type: 'polarArea'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="reporte_tecnicos" style="max-width: 50%; margin: 1px auto; float;none;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Según el [comentario del OP](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50094/personalizaci%c3%b3n-de-gr%c3%a1ficas-chartjs#comment88249_50094), él necesita las opciones del chart _que en tu ejemplo no incluyes_.